# What is the easiest way to get host file adblocking AND security updates?

Tags: root-access, updates, security, lineageos

For a long time I've been using LineageOS to get root access and long-term updates. However my requirements are rather limited: I pretty much only use root access for system-level adblocking, and I want long-term security updates for my phones.

I am wondering whether I can get this without installing an alternate ROM? Do any manufacturers offer this in their stock ROMs? Or can you suggest any other solutions?

Comment: Exclude the IPs/host names required for the updates from the block lists? E.g. [AdAway](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway) supports white lists where you could define such exceptions. For possible alternatives, please see my list for [Ad-Blocker & Filter](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker#group_367) apps. Most require root, though.

Comment: @Izzy : I think my issue boils down to: what is the easiest way to get root and security updates, preferably on a stock ROM?

Comment: Search term: Magisk. I haven't played with it yet, but it offers you a.o. "systemless root" (which shouldn't interfere with any updates). You can find [Magisk Manager in my repo](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.topjohnwu.magisk), which should help you on that path (installing the framework and its modules, which includes the mentioned "systemless root"). If you succeed with that, it would be great if you made the steps an answer to help others.